# Default value for Ember.js model when API fails

Tags: javascript, ember.js

When Ember.js model hook fails, the route transition is failing. How to avoid that. I want to pass some default value like an empty array for messages in case if the ajax call fails.

```
model() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    messages: $.getJSON("localhost:3000/messages")
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Route transition is intended to fail when the model hook fails. Ideally this should be handled in the error action which is fired on model rejection.

```
actions: {
    error(error) {
        //show error message
    }
}
```

However, if at all it is required to send a dummy empty success response on failCases, below snippet can be used:

```
model() {
    Ember.RSVP.hash({
        messages: $.getJSON("localhost:3000/messages")
    }).then(function(hash){
      //success handler, do nothing
    }, function(error) {
      return RSVP.resolve({messages: Ember.A()});
    });
}
```